# Where is FB SDK (v 4.6) native authorization dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdk

I have two questions connected with FB SDK (v4.6)

1) Firstly, using `FBSDKLoginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions` I don't get native UI. `UIApplication` can open FB's scheme (*fbauth2*), I have added necessary items under `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key. I tried all variants of `FBSDKLoginBehavior`: .Native, .Browser...

But as it is written in code description of the SDK. FB SDK login UI can utilize Web interface instead of Native app, seems that my situation is the case.

On my test iPhone, there is FB app. View Controller(VC) from  `logInWithPublishPermissions`(it's view) also valid, its view is visible. In my app there is only one VC

So my question is how to activate native FB login dialog on iOS9?

2) Second question connected with logOut. Because authorization happens using WebView( or probably Safary VC), credentials are cashed on the browser, therefore 
 `logOut` method doesn't erase them, using Graph API( DELETE me/permissions) it's possible to activate permission selection screen.
But it's not possible to login with another account.

Also I tried to activate custom "logout.php" URL : http://www.facebook.com/logout.php?appID=[my_App]&next=[my_app_scheme_url].
But Safari VC displays FB's current user home page, i.e. my attempt to logout completely current user is fruitless.
As it is well known, we can't clear cache of the browser from our apps, due to sandbox limitations.

My question is how to completely deactivate current FB user programmatically, so I can log in from mobile app as another user?

Comment: 1) That is because of changes Appled did in iOS9. Nothing you can change.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I ended with taking previous version of SDK, in which native app is used. However bit code is not enabled there....

Comment: But I still can't perform complete logout, I tried to clear shared cookies, and even cache. However it didn't resolve my issue...

Comment: The Native app experience is worse in iOS9. Because Apple show a popup that the user has to approve. Our testing showed it was worse then the webview.